# WooCommerce single products images doesn't zoom on hover and doesn't change clicking on gallery

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, images

Making WooCommerce e-shop and stuck with single product images. They are absolutely static. When clicking on any image from gallery, then browser links me to separate page with image, but not switching main image. Also on main image doesn't zoom on hover.  [Here is a website uploaded on server](http://display.rentforyou.lt/index.php/produktas/dulkiu-siurblys-numatic-hvr200-henry-900004-620-w/)

Please help to figure out where can be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my solution works for who makes a theme from zero (not using WordPress ready themes)

1. make a Backup from your WordPress theme
2. go to `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce` and find and copy a directory which name is `templates` into `wp-content/themes/your-theme` and rename it to `woocommerce`
3. in your theme directory, create a file and name it `woocommerce.php` and add these lines in it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <?php get_header(); ?>
</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
    <div class="woocommerce">
        <?php woocommerce_content(); ?>
    </div>
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

4. then add this codes to your theme `functions.php` :

```
<?php
function web_add_woocommerce_support() {
    add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
}
add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-zoom' );
add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-lightbox' );
add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-slider' );
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'web_add_woocommerce_support' );
?>
```

note(1): be sure you have `single.php` and `page.php`.

note(2): be sure your `<body>` tags is like this: `<body <?php body_class(); ?>>`

Comment: Thank you. Copied 4. code to `woocommerce.php` and it worked.